# C# : Class attribute of multiple possible types

Tags: c#, variables

I want to have a class in which there is a variable. This variable can be of multiple types, depending on the instance. If in that instance it's initialised as an int, it's an int, if it's initialised as a string, it's a string.
This is what I currently have:

```
class bar
{
    public <???> foo;
}
```

Comment: `class Bar<T> { public T foo; } `

Comment: What is the motivation? How do you plan to use it?

Comment: You can make the class generic, as suggested, but then your property can be of ANY type. If you want just a limited number of types then you would be out of luck unless they all inherit a common base type or implement a common interface.

Comment: As @T.S. points out, you'll get a better answer if you describe why you want to do whatever it is you want to do. It's also worth learning some nomenclature. Classes don't have _variables_ they have _fields_ or _properties_ (or a few other things). Variables are assigned values or references, they are part of your program,  but are not really part of a class you write. How do you expect this _field_ to be initialized? If you want individual _instances_ to be initialized with different types, then each instance will be of different types (say `MyClass<int>` or `MyClass<string>`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These problems can be solved using Generics, with Generics you're able to specify the type of your attributes when you're creating the object, for your problem this is a possible solution

```
public class Bar<T>
{
    public T foo;
}
```

And here is the Generics' documentation,https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics

Comment: Would there be a way to make a List<Bar<T>> of that class, but that not all instances of Bar<T> have the same type? or is that just something impossible?

Comment: You can `class Bar{} class Bar<T> : Bar{}` then `List<Bar>` (or replace `class Bar` with an interface / abstract class).